# Recycling bin access denied on windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, recycle-bin

I've used [unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to remove some files. Now I have issues emptying my bin. I've ran cmd with admin, but am still unable to empty. Rest assured these files are not important.

cmd commands:

[image]

My next idea was to remove the recycle bin entirely, and get it back through control panel - but I wouldn't know about how to do this.

Comment: In the same command prompt, can you post the output from `cacls *` and `dir /q`? The likely hood is your user doesn't own or have permission to delete these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are from a different user ID, that's why you did not have access. You can Take ownership on `$Recycle.Bin`, and propagate it down, and then delete them if you want.

You can always safely delete the whole `$Recycle.Bin`, it comes back right away (clean and empty) without any actions from you; Explorer does that. I remove it every other day or so, for years, never any problems.

Comment: How? I can't view my recycle bin to get ownership or delete it - I can only see it in the command line.

Comment: Oh I can now I ran command as admin - that was obvious!!

Comment: Don't forget that **$RECYCLE.BIN** can be a hidden system folder (with the **H** and **S** attributes set for it). If you seem to have ownership over it, and all the permissions to work with it, but you still get **Access Denied** errors, then you could try `attrib -S -H $RECYCLE.BIN` to make it non-system and non-hidden. After doing what you must, you can `attrib +S +H $RECYCLE.BIN` to restore the original attributes, if the **$RECYCLE.BIN** is still there.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how, but CCleaner did the job.